# Fetch in JavaScript, but less messy?

Tags: javascript, performance, react.js, async-await

I'm trying to separate the fetch logic from the component, but, due to the nature of async/await functions I have to write an async function to call other async function and I wanted to know if that's ok, if it decreases performance and what are the good practices on this.

Here's an example of a fetch function in the postEvent.js file and then used in the page.js, a page component.

```js
//postEvent.js

const postEvent = async newEvent => {
  try {
    const csrf = await getCsrf()
    const apiEnd = "http://localhost:8000/events/";
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrf,
      },
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(newEvent),
    };

    const response = await fetch(apiEnd, options); //1st await
    return {ok: response.ok, json: await response.json()} //2nd await

  } catch (e) {return e;} 
}

//page.js

const response = await postEvent(newEvent) //3rd await
response.ok && Router.push(`/events/${response.json.slug}`)
```

I could avoid the 3rd await if I put all the code in the same file, but it gets too messy, does the number of awaits matter?

I've been looking it up and came to another approach, where I can make a useFetch function and share the state instead of returning a promise, like so:

```js
//useFetch.js

const useEvent = async newEvent => {
  const [data, setData] = useState()

    useEffect(async () => ({
        try {
         const csrf = await getCsrf()
         const apiEnd = "http://localhost:8000/events/";
         const options = {
           method: "POST",
           headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "X-CSRFToken": csrf,
           },
           credentials: "include",
           body: JSON.stringify(newEvent),
         }
        const response = await fetch(apiEnd, options);
        setData(await response.json())

  } catch (e) {return e;} 

    },[newEvent])

return data
}

//page.js

const data = useEvent(newEvent) //3rd await
Router.push(`/events/${data.slug}`)
```

I guess the second way is better than the first, but I still don't understand the need of useEffect if I'm only going to call it once for event

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: Thank you, Toby, I tried to be more clear now 

Comment: To make code less messy you can add a base object that implements basic call, then extend it with specific calls and after that use it within other features.